# How to clean unRAR bug where it crashes my computer by fulling up the disk with data?

Tags: ubuntu, rar

It is a kind of [Zip bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb), which exploded in an anonymous directory.
 I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and, at GUI, I click to extract a `~/Downloads/file.rar`.

It’s is a small 3 Mb file with TXT content, but the extraction is very time consuming and doesn’t finish. Instead it crashes my computer, filling 100% of my disk.

I will not use it again before there is a fix to this bug, but
 **how can I find out where RAR put all the garbage files filling up my computer?**

I don’t see anything in `/tmp` or `~/Downloads`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb

Comment: Thanks @mashuptwice, make sense and seems that [it is not a new problem for Ubuntu](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/-/issues/46)... But, my disk is full,  **some clues about how to scan my disk and check files to be deleted?**

Comment: Sure, cd to / and use `du -d 1 -h` You can also combine it with `sort -h`. `ncdu` is also a nice one, but not included by default, therfore hard to install with a full disk

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice ncurses utility called `ncdu`. It scans directories and lists them by size.

Unfortunately you would need to install it, which is hardly possible with a full disk. Instead you can use GNU `du`, which does exactly the same, only without ncurses.

You might want to start in your root directory `/`

Run `du -d 1 -h | sort -h`

Where `-d` specifies the maximum directory depth du will look into

`-h` will convert bytes to MB or GB automatically (human readable)

and we pipe it through `sort -h` to sort the output by size.

Then simply `cd` into the biggest directory and run `du` again until you've found what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, this is a good staring point (!thanks), and sometimes I using `du -d 1 -h | sort -hr | head`... But need also to scan recently created directiories, perhaps trying by  `ls -dlhur */ | head`  or `ls -dlhtr */ | head`

Comment: The important difference between `ls` and `du` is that `ls` wont show you the size of a directory by its contents, which makes it useless in this case.

Comment: *Size* is not the only information to discriminate "new things", we can check  recent **dates**, after *zip bomb* explosion. My comment is about it, `ls -u`  shows recent things. Sizes are good clues but need complementary information. Your answer will be  incomplete without  (show how to) listing by recent dates.

Comment: @PeterKrauss First of all, the `-u` flag will show no additional information without  `-l`. Second, a file in an archive could preserve its timestamp when extracted. Also your question was about finding **large** files, searching for large files would be **my** first step then. Instead of suggesting that I change my answer because in your opinion it is  incomplete, you could add an answer with **your proposed way** of solving this simple issue. Answering his own question is encouraged on stackexchange.